# Starting Storyboard-Animation over again

Tags: c#, xaml

I am calling a Storyboard-Animation in my code like `MyAnim.Begin();`

But when I call that method again (say, when I click to do it again), 
it interrupts the current running animation and starts from newly from the beginning.

Is there a way, to launch the same animation multiple times without interrupting each other?

I made an explosion effect and I want to let it explode over and over again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Storyboard object contains a completed event. This gets fired when the storyboard has finished running.

I'd suggest something like this:

private object _locker=new object();
private bool _isProcessing;
private int _waitingAnimations;

```
public void Setup()
{
    MyAnim.Completed+=CompletedExecution;
}
private void CompletedExecution(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    bool runAnotherAnim;
    lock(_locker)
    {
        runAnotherAnim=_waitingAnimations>0;
        if(_waitingAnimations>0)
             _waitingAnimations--;

    }
    if(runAnotherAnim)
        MyAnim.Begin();
    else
        _isProcessing=false;
}
public void AddAnimation()
{
   lock(_locker)
   {
       if(_isProcessing)
       {
           _waitingAnimations++;
       }
       else
       {
           _isProcessing=true;
           MyAnim.Begin();

       }
   }

}
```

You'll need to have a look at the arguments provided by the Completed event as I'm doing this from memory, but I've used this before and it does exactly what you're looking to do.